# Get the longest item from each element of the list

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
 a = c("aaaa", "bbbbbbb")
 b = c("a1", "b2", "c33")
 c = "d"
 d = list(a, b, c)
```

How can I get the longest items from each element of the list without a loop? 
In other words the goal is to obtain:

```
"bbbbbbb" "c33" "d"
```

I know how to calculate number of characters:

```
lapply(d, nchar)
[[1]]
[1] 4 7

[[2]]
[1] 2 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

I know how to find position of longest items:

```
lapply(lapply(d, nchar), which.max)
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

But cannot find a way to select items.

I also considered sorting items by number of characters (nchar) in order to select all 1st items by lapply(d, "[[", 1). But without success.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it all into an anonymous function.  And we can use `sapply()` since you want an atomic result.

```
sapply(d, function(x) x[which.max(nchar(x))])
# [1] "bbbbbbb" "c33"     "d"
```